# Show that $\det(A)=(\lambda_1)^{m_1}(\lambda_2)^{m_2}…(\lambda_k)^{m_k}=\prod_{j=1}^k(\lambda_i)^{m_j}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is the problem... I got part a and part b... but I'm lost for part c.
Anyone have a hint of something I can try?

[image]

Comment: How do I type math in the subject line?  Someone always comes behind me and fixes it, but where can I learn to do it myself?

Comment: [Here is a basic MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? It's a standard result with a variety of proofs; what have you tried?

Comment: I'm stuck thinking about when t=0, like with part A.  I'm just staring at this going... but if you don't use part a, then what???

Comment: um.. the jax thing didn't work.

Comment: @DanaHill \left( \right) not \left( )

Comment: surround with $ signs

Comment: keep things simple by avoiding \left and \right and just use ( )

Comment: \det looks better than det

Comment: I almost had it, but thanks jkabrg

Comment: @DanaHill, you've posted graded work (assignment or test) as your question.  And you think it's okay to assign us work that you'll get credit for?

Comment: Seems it might be worth examining your earlier questions/assignments you've posted here prior to now.

Comment: @amWhy No.  I was only looking for some direction, not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $SAS^{-1}=D$ is a diagonal matrix, i.e., $D=\rm {diag}(\lambda_1^{m_1},\cdots ,\lambda_k^{m_k})$. Then the claim is obvious, since
$$
\det(D)=\det(SAS^{-1})=\det(S)\det(A)\det(S^{-1})=\det(A).
$$

Comment: ok, use the fact it is diagonalizable.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since $\;A\;$ is diagonalizable there exists invertible $\;P\;$ such that

$$A=P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&0&\ldots&\ldots&0\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&\ldots&\lambda_1&\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&\ldots&0&\lambda_k\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\lambda_k\end{pmatrix}P\implies$$

$$ \det A=\det\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&0&\ldots&\ldots&0\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&\ldots&\lambda_1&\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&\ldots&0&\lambda_k\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\lambda_k\end{pmatrix}=\prod_{j=1}^k\lambda_j^{m_j}$$

Comment: ok, use the fact it is diagonalizable.  Thanks